# process hangs on socket recvmsg call while receiving complete mmapped memory block

Tags: c, sockets, mmap, recvmmsg

I have a server process (C program)which does mmap for a physical memory of size around 70MB and when I'm sending this entire memory block over socket to a client process, My socket send api returns success but client keeps waiting for the message to receive. The problem comes only when I'm sending complete mmapped block. If I'm sending less than that then this issue never comes

Comment: please post your code. Also, what's the return value for recvmsg? Are you calling it in a loop?

Comment: I can't post code here but yes I'm calling recvmsg in loop and it gets stuck there only without any return value. I know we can set timeout for this to come out but that's not what I want because same code works fine when I'm sending less amount of data from same mmapped memory chunk. Problem comes only when I'm sending complete mmapped size of data.